# A main activity call a intent and the original receiver was killed

Tags: android, memory, receiver

A main activity call a intent to do something(like install a certain apk)and main activity have a receiver to monitor the intent ACTION; but the problem is, for some case, main activity 
will be killed if the memory is not enough, the intent receiver too. How do I keep the receiver live ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your receiver out of activity, and declair it in your AndroidManifest.xml.